# Python scapy: pcap file read, manipulate and write pcap

Tags: python, pcap, scapy

I want to read a pcap file using python scapy, manipulate the TCP payload (e.g. delete the current payload and replace it with 0s) and write the manipulated packets to a new pcap file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) and dpkt. It assumes that IP is the L2 protocol.

```
import dpkt
from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.tcp import TCP

for ts, raw_pkt in pcap.pcap(file_path):
    ip = IP(raw_pkt[14:])
    if(type(ip) != IP):
        continue
    tcp = ip.data
    if(type(tcp) != TCP):
        continue
    do_something_with(tcp.data)
```

Comment: IMHO writing to the new pcap file is missing (which is a pitty - because this is what I'm looking for).

Comment: @AndreasFlorath I have some python code to read and write pcaps. Will dig it out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much - I figured it out myself yesterday using scapy and wrpcap.

Answer (score 2):

FTR, to answer the op question,

```
from scapy.all import *
with PcapWriter("output.pcap", sync=True) as outs:
    with PcapReader("input.pcap") as ins:
        for pkt in ins:
            if TCP in pkt:
                pkt[TCP].remove_payload()
            outs.write(pkt)
```

Comment: Dear @Cukic0d, it removed the payload but when I construct the packet I am getting "25 bytes missing in capture file". Shall I decrease that packet[IP].len to avoid the mistake?

Comment: You can set it to `None` (same for checksums, lengths...) and it Scapy will re-compute them